# Prevent R shiny handsontable from resetting to default value

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I have created the following  shiny App

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(  
sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel = "Inputparameter", 
            selectInput(inputId = "Name", label = "Name", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))),                
            mainPanel (rHandsontableOutput(outputId = 'Adjusttable', width ='100%', height = 100%')))

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
output$Adjusttable<-renderRHandsontable({
DF = data.frame(ID = 1:7,'Column2' = 0, Start = "D",FM="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(DF)[names(DF)=='Column2']<- input$Name
names(DF)[names(DF)=='FM']<-'FM'
DF$ID<-NULL
rhandsontable(DF, width = 280, height = 677,stretchH = "all")  %>%
  hot_col(col = "Start", type = "dropdown", source = c("Fw", "Sw"), fillHandle = 
  list(direction='vertical', autoInsertRow=TRUE))%>%
  hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = TRUE, allowColEdit = FALSE)
  }, quoted = FALSE )}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The following results in an app with an editable table. When we fill values in the table,, and change the  item in the name drop down, the values get reset to 0 and the table defaults to its default state. Is there a way to fill the table, change the number of rows, etc , change the name input and avoid resetting the table. I request someone to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(DT)

DF <- data.frame(ID = 1:7,Column2 = 0, Start = "D",FM="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(DF)[names(DF)=='FM']<-'FM'
DF$ID<-NULL

ui <- fluidPage(  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( "Inputparameter", 
                selectInput(inputId = "Name", label = "Name", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))),                
    mainPanel( rHandsontableOutput(outputId = 'hot', width ='100%', height = '100%') 
               , DTOutput("t1")
               ) 
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=DF)
  observe({
    input$Name
    names(DF1$data)[1] <- input$Name
  })
  
  output$hot<-renderRHandsontable({
    
    rhandsontable(DF1$data, width = 280, height = 677,stretchH = "all")  %>%
      hot_col(col = "Start", type = "dropdown", source = c("Fw", "Sw"), fillHandle = 
                list(direction='vertical', autoInsertRow=TRUE)) %>%
      
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = TRUE, allowColEdit = FALSE)
  }, quoted = FALSE )
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)){
      DF1$data <- (hot_to_r(input$hot))
    } 
  })
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT(DF1$data)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you. Moving the dataframe creation step outside the handson table loop is an important step.  It should be possible to dynamicaly alter the number of columns from th sidebar also